# Time of query very long

Tags: c#, visual-studio, elasticsearch, nest

i'm new on the world of elasticsearch and i'm trying to code it in c# with the NEST aPI.

I succed to index some doc with content but when i try to search, the research take ~4sec.

I use visual studio 2012

I hope you can help me :)

```
[ElasticType(Name = "document")]
public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Store = true)]
    public string Titre { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.Attachment, TermVector = TermVectorOption.WithPositionsOffsets, Store = true)]
    public Attachment File { get; set; }
}

public class Attachment
{
    [ElasticProperty(Name = "_content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Name = "_content_type")]
    public string ContentType { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Name = "_name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

static int i = 0;
static int j = 0;
```

This is my class's declarations

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //New connection
    //var node = new Uri("http://serv-intra:9200");

    var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200/");

    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(
        node,
        defaultIndex: "document"
        );

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    //Creation of my index with mapping
    //client.CreateIndex("document", c => c
    //  .AddMapping<Document>(m => m.MapFromAttributes())
    //  );

    //function for index
    //feignasse(client);

    var query = Query<Document>.Term("_all", "chu");

    var searchResults = client.Search<Document>(s => s
            .From(0)
            .Size(200)
            .Query(query)
    );
}

protected static void feignasse(ElasticClient client)
{
    // Create new stopwatch
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    // Begin timing
    stopwatch.Start();

    Indexation(@"\\serv-intra\Documents", client);

    // Stop timing
    stopwatch.Stop();
}

//This is my function for index
protected static void Indexation(string path, ElasticClient client)
{
    string[] rootDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(path);

    string[] rootFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path);

    foreach (string nomfich in rootFiles)
    {

        if (nomfich.Length < 256)
        {
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(nomfich);

            var attachement = new Attachment();
            attachement.Content = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(nomfich));
            attachement.Name = file.Name;
            attachement.ContentType = GetMimeType(file.Extension);

            var document = new Document
            {
                Id = i,
                Titre = file.Name,
                File = attachement,

            };

            var index = client.Index(document);
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            j++;
        }
    }

    foreach (string newPath in rootDirectories)
    {
        Indexation(newPath, client);
    }
```

So i explain you, in my server i have a sharing of doc, and i just travel him in order to catch all my doc and index then in elasticsearch

I have to node with 0 replica and 5 shards

Thanks you

Comment: Visual Studio is telling you that if you want to debug ElasticSearch itself, you will need to [download the code](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch) and run from source.

Comment: Thx for you reply, so then i just put the code at c:\code\ ?

Edit : I have the code source on my desktop but i don't understand what u mind ?

Comment: More over when i compile in my server, my research take ~5sec but ElapsedMilliseconds function return 1000ms so don't understand why my request take so long time

Comment: Adding the code at c:\code may work if the versions match: otherwise you would need to add the ElasticSearch code to your solution, rather than referencing the DLL. But it seems unlikely there's a problem with that code, and Lucene is usually very fast, can you get any information about the index or index usage from ElasticSearch?

Comment: Look out my answer down ;)

Comment: You should edit that into your question, rather than posting it as an answer (which it isn't). Also take the opportunity to retitle your question to make it clear that your question is about query time rather than the source code.

Comment: Okay i have edit my first post and the title ;) thx

Comment: Looks good. I hope someone can help you!

Comment: As ever with performance issues, you need to identify *where* your performance issue actually lies. You've indicated that `ElapsedMilliseconds` indicates the search took ~1,000ms. This is the work done by Elasticsearch, the rest of the time consumed is on "other" tasks. It could be network transfer for example. Method `Indexation` shows that you're converting the content of files to Base64 strings and adding them to the document, could the time involved in transferring those strings be costly?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, well i've updat settings of my server, up to 12GB Ram and 150Go DD, so performance are now better :D, but.. there is all the time a but.. i suspect my field containing my file encoded in base 64 to slow the query.. so how can i do to search in this field in my research but don't return him in my array ?